# Apache is forbidden some very specific pages

Tags: apache, homebrew, http-status-code-403

I have a Sites folder inside my user directory, where I put all of my apache project files, the weird thing is that I can access all of my folders, except for the main route "localhost/" which, of course, has no index.html document on it, its just folders, but I know I should be able to see something like this:

Index of Sites.

```
  .project1
  .project2
  .project3
```

Instead, I get this 
403 Forbidden

On my new job I was assigned to this Mac PC that belonged to someone else, and this person of course needed the same tools that I have been asked to download, they told me to uninstall all of that software and install it all over again (which I did), mainly the software that I'm using is an apache server with homebrew.

I have always had this problem, but I ignored it because I thought, well, do I really need to see an "index of Sites" page when I can manually change to whatever folder I want? my answer was, not really.

But yesterday they asked me to download webpack and nodeJs, and I did, so I made a dummy project with webpack that contained all of the js and config files, but it didn't have an index.html file. And surprise surprise, I got a 403 forbidden error when entering the dummy folder in localhost.

So I'm guessing that my apache for some reason is giving me 403 errors when I do not have an index.html file or an index.php file to show.

Have you ever experienced something like this?

Comment: Are directory indexes enabled? See [the Apache doc on Directory Listing Configuration](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings).

Comment: Yes they are, i remember sseeing something like this:DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

Comment: That's for index *files* ("index.html", "index.php", etc); for autogenerated listings, you need something like `Options +Indexes`.

Comment: Okay, i will try that but where do i put that in?, there are like 3 <Directory> tags, one of them has no attributes, the second one has the location of my projects and the last one has a strange location.